# Не работает io.sockets, node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

```
...
var SSP = io.of('/SSP').on('connection', function(socket) 
{
    // не работает 
    io.sockets.in(room).emit("ready",'test');
    // работает
    socket.to(room).emit('ready','Вы успешно подключились к игре, стол: '+room+', '+'Ожидаем соперника');
...
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает отправка сообщения всем пользователям  ?

И можно ли отправлять сообщения на конкретные сокет id,(есть массив сокет айди и на всех них сообщение)

**Правка:**

**клиент:**

```
    socket.on('ready', function(data) 
    {
        console.log('ready:'+data);
    });
```

**сервер:**

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit("ready",'test');
```

Не работает именно сообщение всем (включая текущего пользователя).
При этом если послать любой другой запрос, например текущему пользователю или всем кроме себе, то все отлично работает.

Получается:

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit("ready",'test 1'); // не работает
socket.to(room).emit('ready','test 2'); // работает
socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('ready','test 3');// работает
```

Comment: недостаточно данных для совета

Comment: если вы пишите io.sockets.in(room)..... значит это событие должно быть обработано на клиенте вот так socket.on("ready",function(message){}) где message это объект который должен быть передан на сервере т.е это будет примерно так: на сервере
io.sockets.in(room).emit("ready",message); 
на клиенте socket.on("ready",function(message){
    $("#user").append($("<b/>",{class:"client"}).text(message));
})
Объясните 2 вопрос поподробней

Answer (score 1):

не правильно вы делаете.

отправляем сообщение на сервер

```
`$("#send").click(function(){ 
    //извлекаем сообщение с инпута         
    var text=$("#text").val(),
    //получаем имя пользователя
    name=$("#user").text();
    $("#text").val("");
    //отправляем на сервер
    socket.emit("ready",text,name);
});`
на сервере

socket.on("ready",function(message,name){
//где message наше сообщение name имя пользователя
//на сервере убеждаемся что сообщение пришло смотрим в консоль
    socket.emit("sendmessage","server",message);
//и опять пуляем на клиент
io.sockets.emit("addmessage",message);
```

`}`)

//на клиенте обрабатываем событие полученное с сервера

```
    socket.on("addmessage",function(message){
       console.log(message);
       $("#chat").append($("<b/>",{
            class:"message"
        }).text(message));
     });
```

Если вы хотите отправлять сообщение на конкретные id создавайте комнаты где будут общаться ограниченный круг людей

Comment: Забавно, клиент

            $("#send").click(function()
            { 
                alert('Попадаем');
                socket.emit("ready",'text','name');
            })

            socket.on("addmessage",function(message)
            {
               console.log(message);
            });

 сервер:

    socket.on("ready",function(message,name)
    {
        io.sockets.emit("addmessage",message);
        
        console.log(message);// все ок
    })

не попадем сюда:

            socket.on("addmessage",function(message)
            {
               console.log(message);
            });